# Error syncing load balancer: services is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes

I made k8s cluster with kubeadm on GCE, and I want to make my `ingress-nginx-controller` service to use type `LoadBalancer`.

To do this, I first edited `kube-controller-manager.yaml` on my control plane node.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
...
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    ...
    - --cloud-provider=gce    # <= Added this line
...
$ sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Then edited service type.

```
$ kubectl edit svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
...
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
...
```

Then I got an error like below.

```
$ kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
...
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                -------
  Normal   Type                    19m (x2 over 156m)     service-controller  NodePort -> LoadBalancer
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer    4m46s (x18 over 156m)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  4m46s (x5 over 18m)    service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: services "ingress-nginx-controller" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cloud-provider" cannot patch resource "services/status" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx"
```

I cannot understand what this error message is saying. How can I deal with it?

**EDIT**

I added `Role` and `RoleBinding` manually like below, then the error messages are not shown but `EXTERNAL-IP` is in `<pending>`.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: cloud-provider
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - patch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cloud-provider
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: cloud-provider
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cloud-provider
  namespace: kube-system
```

---

```
$ kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.105.43.38   <pending>     80:30269/TCP,443:31275/TCP   8d

$ kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
...
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                    From                Message
  ----    ------                ----                   ----                -------
  Normal  Type                  7m35s (x2 over 3h55m)  service-controller  LoadBalancer -> NodePort
  Normal  Type                  7m15s (x3 over 4h14m)  service-controller  NodePort -> LoadBalancer
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  117s (x44 over 4h14m)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
```

Comment: you need to assing role to the computer instance https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.loadBalancerAdmin

Comment: Your problem resolved?